# How do I detect whether a user is inactive on webpage using Spring-MVC?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I am attempting to implement a feature where I can detect if the user has been inactive on the webpage for more than 5 minutes.

What's the best way to go about doing this using Spring?

Clarification: Inactive means the user has not interacted with the page for 5 minutes.

Comment: What exactly qualifies as inactive?

Comment: You probably want a custom sessionListener implementing HttpSessionListener

Comment: Inactive meaning, user hasn't interacted with the page for 5 minutes.

Comment: have you checked this http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-handler-interceptor ?

Comment: That seems too complicated for my needs. Is it possible to set a javascript timeout on page and somehow relay that info back?

Comment: Yes -- but that won't work if the user closes the browser. Is that want you want?